# Create "root like" mesh using graph data Blender Python API on Blender 3.4.1

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I would like to create a "root-like mesh system" using only the Python API of Blender as I can use it in different projects and generate a large number of meshes without opening Blender.

Before this Blender part, I have created a script that generates an undirected graph and store the ID of each node, it's coordinate, parents IDs and children IDs in a JSON file.

Given that data I would like to create a mesh of the graph.

I have different ideas about how to investigate such as:

- Create vertex at each node and vertices between them, then add a cylinder mesh around it
- Create splines following the graph pattern then add a cylinder mesh around it

I would like some advice about how to proceed and if you have any other ideas.

Comment: Also skin modifier can be used for this. The disadvantage of skin modifier is that it has a remesh-like (or boolean-like) behavior in that it creates inconsistent animations with sudden changes to topology. The advantage is that it creates (sometimes buggy) smoothed connections on intersections.

Comment: Oh nice, I did not knew about this one. Thank you very much, the roots are empty inside, does it create holes within the root at each intersections ?

Comment: The skin modifier will not create internal faces https://i.imgur.com/LMGD52o.png

Comment: Nice ! Have you done this example using the Blender Python API ?

Comment: No, but adding a skin modifier in Python is trivial: `C.object.modifiers.new('', 'SKIN')` and in my case I also added a subdivision modifier `C.object.modifiers.new('', 'SUBSURF').levels = 2`

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it !

Comment: It works well but now I would like to modify randomly but still in a coherent way the shape of the skin around the graph. I tried with skin data but the documentation is not really clear about how to use it. Could you highlight me ?